# 404 Error from Azure Front Door and APIM.How can I solve this problem?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-front-door

I want to link APIM to Azure Front Door.
So,In Azure Front Door,I set the Front Door backend host to the APIM GateWay URL.
Path of HEALTH PRORVE is "/"
And, I accessed the Front Door URL.
Then, "{"statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found"} " is displayed.
Is there a problem with APIM?
sorry for my bad english.
please help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.